# alternative LaTeX-code for round parenthesis ( )

Tags: brackets, delimiters

For square brackets one can use `\lbrack \rbrack` instead of `[ ]`
Is there also an alternative LaTeX command to get normal parentheses (i.e. round brackets) instead of `(` and `)`.

<sub>Is there a better / more complete overview than:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Brackets_and_Parentheses</sub>

Comment: Not by default; `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` exist because in the olden times keyboards might lack `[` and `]`. In LaTeX they can also be used for avoiding confusion with optional arguments. There is no such case for `(` and `)`.

Comment: The `mathtools` package provides the macros `\lparen` and `\rparen`, which evaluate to `(` and `)`, respectively. These macros are discussed in section 3.7.1 of the package's user guide. (Type `texdoc mathtools` at a command prompt in order to view the user guide in a pdf viewer.)

Comment: Mico's comment should be turned into the answer to the question, it is correct.  My use case for this is that I have my editor (TextMate) set up to recognise both parentheses and curly braces as forming groups - helps a lot with making sure there is the right number of them - but this leads to disaster when parentheses are not matched within braces or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the user guide you reference in your query:

[image]

I guess you're asking if there are macros for the opening "fences" `(`, `[`, `\{` etc as well as for their closing counterparts. The answer is "yes":

[image]

A big advantage in writing `\lvert` or `\rvert` instead of `|`, and `\lVert` and `\rVert` instead of just `\|`, is as follows: `|` and `\|` have math status "ord", whereas the others have status "math-open" and "math-close", respectively. This can be very useful at times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\lparen\ \lbrack\ \lbrace\ \langle\ \lvert\ \lVert$ \quad
$\rparen\ \rbrack\ \rbrace\ \rangle\ \rvert\ \rVert$
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are more e.g. `\lfloor`, `\lrloor`, `\lceil` and `\rceil`

Comment: @Jakob  - You're absolutely correct. My answer focused just on the symbols shown in the table of the reference guide you noted in your query.